# Generalized likelihood ratio test - discrete data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value, likelihood-ratio

Let $X_1, \dots , X_n$ be a random sample from an exponential distribution with the density function $f(x \mid \theta) = \theta \exp(-\theta x)$. Also $H_0 : \theta = 1$ versus $H_a : \theta \neq 1$, level of significance $\alpha=5\%$.

**Solution**:
Applying the likelihood ratio test I got the following for my ratio: $$(\theta_0 \overline{X} \exp (-\theta_0\overline{X} + 1))^n \,,$$

so we have a rejection region of: 
$$ \overline{X} \exp(-\theta_0\overline{X}) \leq \theta_0^{-1}ec^{1/n}\,,$$
since $\theta_0=1$ simplifies to:
$$\overline{X} \exp(-\overline{X}) \leq ec^{1/n} \,.$$

**Question:** if given a set of $n$ data points, how do I determine whether I reject $H_0$ and how do I determine the p-value?

Is there any way to verify the solution in R?

**Edit**:
I understand that the exponential is a continuous distribution. The problem asked to derive the generalized likelihood ratio test given the above information, from which I got the first equation. It notes that when $\theta=1$ than $\Sigma_iX_i$ follows $\Gamma(n,\frac{1}{\theta})$.

The part I am asking about, states that we observed $5$ data points: $0.33, 0.24, 0.33, 0.44, 1.72$, would we accept or reject our  $H_0$ and to find the p-value.

Looking at the above inequality we know all variable but $c$, I think we can use the fact that it follows the Gamma and that the significance level is $5\%$ to find our value of $c$. So that $95\%$ coverage is attained, $2.5\%$ on each side. If the inequality proves true, we accept the hypothesis, reject it otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. I'm glad to see you've shown us the progress you've made so far, and thinking about how to verify your solution computationally is a nice idea. What do *you* think you could do to determine the *p*-value and rejection decision?

Comment: There seems to be a typographical error in your title ("descrite data") but I'm not sure whether you mean "discrete" - the exponential distribution is continuous, so this has rather confused me.

Comment: It appears you have accidentally created two accounts - [see here for how to merge them](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This means you can edit your own questions instantly rather than wait for other users to approve your edits. I'm still not sure about the "discrete" data - if your data are really discrete, could you explain what you mean by that in the question?

Comment: Are you sure about your rejection region? Where did the $\theta_0$ in the $\exp$ term go?

Comment: @user271496, if you are the OP, please register & merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.